# If else condition in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, actionview

I want my content display in different color in odd or even order.
But if I write in this way, only can display  `%div.review.alert.alert-success`

How could I achieve my goal?

```
    -if cycle('odd', 'even') == 'odd'
      %div.review.alert.alert-info
    -else
      %div.review.alert.alert-success

      %h4
        = review.username
      %hr
      %h4
        = review.save_hours
      %h4
        = review.suggestion
```

Comment: you indentation is not proper. If you observe the username, save_hours and suggestion are only displayed in else statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [cycle](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/cycle) within a loop.  Are you doing that?

And this would make tidier code:

```
.review.alert{class: cycle('alert-info', 'alert-success')}

  %h4
    = review.username
  %hr
  ...
```

Unless you meant to only include username, save_hours & suggestion every other time?